Doubt about usage of the Intermediate Value Theorem?
There is one example in Lang's Calculus book where he uses inflection/critical points and associated information to plot $f(x)=x^3-2x+1$, after he shows how it's done, there is a remark:



I'm a bit confused, when he says:

Hence $f'(x)$ is either $>0$ for all $x<-\sqrt{2/3}$ or $f'(x)<0$ for all $x<-\sqrt{2/3}$ by the intermediate value theorem.

Where exactly is the IVT used here?

$f'(x)\neq 0$ for $x <-\sqrt {2/3}$ so it cannot assume both positive and negative values for $x <-\sqrt {2/3}$.

@geetha290krm But we must set values for the intervals in the theorem, no? What are the intervals we are using here?

The interval is $(-\infty, -\sqrt {2/3})$.

Suppose for some $a < b < - \sqrt{2/3}$ we have $f'(a) < 0, f'(b) > 0$, then by the IVT there is some point $c \in (a,b)$ with $f'(c) = 0$
